# Video sequencer playback doesn't work

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to edit a video in the sequencer but video playback just doesn't work, it only works if it's played backwards for some reason, when I press the play animation button it only skips a frame and then it stops

Here's a video of the problem (I'm using the 3.0 Alpha but the problem still is present in the 2.93.4 Stable): https://youtu.be/YFoRtFUMXl8

Comment: Ok, I found a solution, I just had to change my audio device in Preferences/System/Audio Device to either OpenAL or PulseAudio. I guess it worked backwards because it doesn't do audio backwards

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by setting the Playback: Sync option to *Play Every Frame*.

Answer (score -2):

I had to go to *Playback: Sync* and it was set to *Sync with Audio* by default.

I selected *Play Every Frame* and it finally started working.